# How frequently do traders rebalance their gamma hedges?

Tags: hedging, gamma, delta-neutral

Say, for instance, that you've set up a delta-neutral straddle (i.e. you are long volatility, short time decay) and want to dynamically hedge your gamma in order to offset losses due to theta. Is there a commonly used framework that compares the cost of rebalancing the hedge against the growing theta exposure?

I recall reading that a 1 s.d. move represents the break even point between gamma and theta, so that or a slightly larger move that would cover both theoretical loss due to time decay and the real, fixed execution cost associated with rebalancing seems like a reasonable place to start, but I'm not sure why that would be the only place to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly used procedures are to hedge;

1. when a 1 SD move has happened, or
2. when your delta position exceeds some risk limit, or
3. once a day, or
4. based on your desired delta position.

All are used. I personally prefer (2).

Comment: Thanks for these - do you know if anyone tries to factor in the execution cost of hedging? Will write up a second question asking more about how risk limits are derived in practice

Comment: My experience is in liquid markets where bid/offers are quite small, so doesn't impact the decision much.  If bid-offers were wide you would transact less often than otherwise , that's true.

Comment: This [paper][1] on "Empirical properties of straddle returns" has an interesting analysis of the profitability of straddles under different rebalancing frequencies.  

  [1]: https://risk.edhec.edu/sites/risk/files/EDHEC_Working_Paper_Empirical_Properties_of_Straddle_Returns.pdf